# HTML video not working

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to get a video to play locally but it isn't working. the file is 'wildlife.mp4,' however, it doesn't play it is just a blank video box? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>video</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="wildlife.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Try closing your video tag.

Comment: check this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070724/safari-html5-video-mp4-not-playing-in-htaccess-folder

Answer (score 3):

Video tag is not closed.
Add autoplay if you want the video to play automatically.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>video</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" autoplay="autoplay" height="240" controls>
<source src="wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="wildlife.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script on Windows the browser can check the file type associated with the video ( wildlife.mp4 ). On my system ( W7) I clicked the -Properties- on the video file and CHANGed the -Type of file- from VLC (which is the default on my system) to Windows Media player and all was sorted.
Hope this helps.